# Alert Javascript Errors when javascript fails?

Tags: javascript

When I have a fatal error in javascript making the app not usable, like this one:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'
```

Is it possible to catch it and display it somehow? like **replacing the body** or **alerting**?

So in other words, a way to run javascript code if there is a javascript code error...

I can't open the web inspector on runtime when I'm inside a crashed page, this is because I'm using webkit outside of a browser who would normally be able to open and display the webinspector on a crashed page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define [**window.onerror**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror) callback in the very first `<script>` loaded on the page, like this:

```
<script>
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line) {
    alert(msg + ' appeared on the line #' + line);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I love it when there are such easy to implement solutions, saves me hours. thanks a lot, I can now redirect errors to a native error handler. Don't really understand why document is able to perform a callback on crashed pages while no other valid object is able to run... but at least it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
try{
    adddlert("Welcome guest!");
}catch(err){
    alert(err.message);
}
```

Comment: I'll try the whole webapp (2k lines) inside the try handler.. not sure if runtime errors will be catched this way...

Comment: The OP's example is a syntax error though, not a runtime error.